# Div slide up on CSS hover

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transitions

I have `div` that is hidden and appears when you hover over another `div`.
When the hidden `div` appears I also want to have a slide up transition.

I have created this https://jsfiddle.net/dx34fn5q/

**HTML**

```
<div class="clickhere">Hover here</div>
<div class="showme">Show me</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .showme {display: none;}
 .clickhere:hover + .showme {display: block;}
```

What additional CSS would I need to add to make the slide up transition?

An example of the transition I want to achieve can be seen on the icons section (second row) [of this website](https://candykittens.co.uk/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of hiding the element with `display: none` you can hide it with `opacity: 0` and offset it with `transform: translateY(100%)` and then smoothly animate those properties with a CSS transition on hover:

```css
.showme {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
}

.clickhere:hover + .showme {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="clickhere">Hover here</div>
<div class="showme">Show me</div>
```